# Python : number of characters in text file

Tags: python

I am trying to get the number of characters in a file.
But when I use 'len' on an imported txt file, it returns the number of bits instead of the number of characters.

```
text1=open('text1.txt','r+').read()
print len(text1)

1256664
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: show us the file content. because its working fine for me.

Comment: I tried this with a simple test file with just `hello world\n` in it and it seems to count the number of characters just fine (returns 12). Could you try that and see if it works? Also try printing `text1` to see if its actually a string; you might be reading it in binary mode.

Comment: @fsong when i print the text it doesn't return as a string, you are right, it prints with indents and tabs etc... when i look at the file info, it says size : 1,256,664 bytes

Comment: @joaquin i downloaded an ebook as a text file here http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: So there's no actual issue? Everything is working as it should?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the problem is that your file is encoded, say in UTF-8, then you should decode it before counting characters:

```
utf8_text=open('text1.txt','r+').read()
unicode_data = utf8_text.decode('utf8')

print len(unicode_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

That does *not* return the number of bits!

```
with open('abc') as f:
    print len(f.read())
```

Results in `4` when the contents are `def\n`.  Maybe your text is encoded with something like UTF-16/32/... which uses multiple bytes for one character?  Please elaborate on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's the number of `bytes` read. In case you are on linux: `ls -lh text1.txt` should give you `1227K`.

This number includes the number of characters in your file, but line endings are also counted.

PS my answer doesn't take into account the file encoding. Under UTF-8, characters will no longer be single 1-byte characters like in ASCII.

Comment: No, it counts the number of bytes, as you said in your first sentence: Suppose you are reading a file encoded using UTF-8 and its content is: `äöüß\n`, len(f.read()) will return `9`.