# python counting characters in a file

Tags: file, python-3.x

I'm trying to find out how to count how many characters there are in a file here is my code so far:

```
def file_size(filename):
num_chars = 0
open(filename, 'r')
num_chars += len(filename)

print(file_size('data.txt'))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python : number of characters in text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931767/python-number-of-characters-in-text-file)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `len()` after you [`file.read()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

```
def file_size(filename):
   with open(filename) as f:
      return len(f.read())

print(file_size('data.txt'))
```

Comment: You probably meant: `with open(filename) as f` ;) Other than that this should work fine, plus one.

Answer (score 1):

To get the size of a file (without having to read the whole thing), use `os.stat`;

```
import os

def filezise(path):
    res = os.stat(path);
    return res.st_size
```

How many *characters* the file contains, depends on what is in the file.

- If it is binary data, the word "characters" has little meaning. Although it is then often interpreted such that characters are bytes.
- Plain ASCII text, and other encodings e.g. latin-1 use one byte per character.
- Other encodings such as UTF-32 use multiple bytes per character, but they do use the same number of bytes for each character.
- If the file uses a [variable-width encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding), such as UTF-8 and UTF-16, you will have to examine the whole contents to decipher the amount of characters.

Comment: OP doesn't mention whether or not the file has unicode

Comment: st_size  = size of file, in bytes, not the number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open(file_name)
text = f.readlines()
print(sum(map(len, text)))
```

Comment: There is a `python-3.x` tag in the question, so you might want to put parenthesis to your `print()`. ;) Other than that this should work fine, plus one.

Answer (score 0):

I used a nested for loop to count the amount of characters in a given file.

```
#open file for reading
file = open("data.txt", "r")
#set count variable equal to 0
count = 0
#outer loop iterates over each line in file.
for line in file:
    #inner loop iterates over each individual character in each line.
    for character in line:
        #check to see if that individual character is in fact a letter use str.isalpha()
        if character.isalpha():
           #if condition is true count must increase by 1
           count += 1
print("they're {} characters in such file".format(count))
#Don't forget to close the file! I tend to close all file from which they have been opened.
file.close()
```